# .htaccess not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess file isn't working.  I have checked that it is in the root directory.  I also verified that it's code is correct. When I type random letters/numbers into the .htaccess I do not get a 500 error. When i open my apache error log, it gives me this error:

```
[Mon Jan 16 20:28:37 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Mon Jan 16 20:28:41 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Jan 16 20:28:41 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Jan 16 20:28:44 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I don't know what to do.

http.conf:

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that the cause of the .htaccess file not working is anything to do with the favicon? If your website already had a .htaccess file in the root, make sure you take a backup of it before playing around with anything ;) To test whether your .htaccess file is working, just type a load of random stuff in it, upload it to your web site's root and then try to access your website. If you get an error 500 (server error) then it is working. What are you trying to configure in your .htaccess file?

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? What's the expected behavior? And what's the actual behavior? And what's the contents of your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: "`And what's the contents of your .htaccess file?`"

Comment: @Gerben "When I type random letters/numbers into the .htaccess I do not get a 500 error." the contents are currently "sdfds33g3g3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few possible reasons your random, invalid, `.htaccess` file would not cause an http error 500 (internal server error):

- Incorrect file name. It must be `.htaccess`. The first character is a dot. The last character is a lower case 's'. Hidden extensions might cause problems because an incorrect file name could appear to be correct.
- The file location is incorrect. Try placing the file next to your html files, in the same folder. If that works, you could move the file up one folder and try again.
- The Apache configuration does not allow for `.htaccess` files. If the configuration option `AllowOverride` is set to `None` in the apache configuration files (for the specified domain), then Apache will not look for any `.htaccess` files.

Also note that `.htaccess` files are ignored when you access your files using the `file://` protocol.

**Update**

The paths used in `.htaccess` refer to file system paths, not url paths. Based on the `.htaccess` content you posted, nobody has access to any files on your webserver. I would suggest something like:

```
<Directory />
    # Security first, deny everything that's not explicitly allowed.
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny, allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/webroot>
    # This is the part that should be accessible
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow, deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Your `.htaccess` file should be in `/path/to/webroot`
Note that you should change `/path/to/webroot` to something sensible that matches your file system.

Comment: I have verified all of these and still no 500 error.  could there be anything else?  I don't need to include anything on my html files, right?  i've simply placed the .htaccess inside my root directory.

Comment: also there are two other http.conf files in my apache2 folder, http.conf.save and http.conf.save.1.  I just want to verify that having these files will not change anything.  I didn't create the files. there were just there.

Comment: Those files are probably backup files, it shouldn't hurt to have them.

Comment: so could there be any other problem?

Comment: They are backups of the main configuration file for Apache - httpd.conf. Their presence in the directory will not cause any issues. If the .htaccess files are not working you could try contacting your web host to check they have not been disabled

Comment: what platform are you on? .htaccess files only work on Linux-based systems